# Server's internet connection restarted and now I can't connect via HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: networking, server, apache2, internet, html

### Overview

I have a *LAMP* stack installed on my Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 server which hosts a number of websites using Virtual Hosts.

They have been working fine and out of mind for the last few months.

However, yesterday I had a blackout and the router got assigned a IPv4 address.

### Issue

When visiting the new IP address, the browser doesn't load any page, and I see an `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error.

I've rebooted the server and used `sudo service apache2 restart` but I can't access the IP (as I previously was able) from a browser.

I can access the IP through the LAN (`192.168.0.23`) and I checked the router settings and the HTTP/HTTPS port forwarding (`:80` and `:443`) are both still there with the correct internal IP address associated.

### Question

Is there a service that I'm missing? Is there anything else I need to restart for the virtual hosting to come back online?

Comment: Check The host file on the client and update with the new ip